# Return Value from a list with multiple criteria for different date ranges in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of data from where I need to return a value based on a criteria to choose from a date range. I have a list below where I need to find the company name Occidental Petroleum Corporation to come in place of ??. All the data is in excel in different columns.

Many Thanks.

1. Al-Rayyan    Qatar   01-Jan-00   Others
2. Al-Rayyan    Qatar   01-Jan-01   Anadarko Petroleum Corporation
3. Al-Rayyan    Qatar   01-Jan-08   Occidental Petroleum Corporation
4. Al-Rayyan    Qatar   31-Dec-14   Occidental Qatar Energy Company LLC

**Al-Rayyan Qatar   03-May-09   ??**

Comment: How does your data behave in the excel? Which columns contain which information?

Comment: Hi Surani, Column 1 is Al-Rayyan Column 2 is Qatar Column 3 is Date and Column 4 is company name.